# Chrome downloads PNGs from S3 but views them from Imgur

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-s3

When opening a link to a PNG image on Imgur, for example https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZPcm.png, in Google Chrome, then the image is displayed in the browser.

But when uploading a PNG to a bucket on Amazon S3, when the link is opened, the image not viewed rather it is asked to download. I've tried setting the 'Content-Type' on the S3 image, but wihout luck.

Headers on Imgur:

```
{'Date': 'Tue, 11 Aug 2020 10:31:05 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'image/png', 'Content-Length': '18782', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Set-Cookie': '__cfduid=d7f5ddd0f60e3db9cc4edffeedd30f3e71597141865; expires=Thu, 10-Sep-20 10:31:05 GMT; path=/; domain=.imgur.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax', 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=315360000', 'ETag': '"187ec0eb8d9d14b438e87ea698efac33"', 'Expires': 'Fri, 09 Aug 2030 10:31:05 GMT', 'Last-Modified': 'Thu, 07 Dec 2017 11:01:07 GMT', 'x-amz-version-id': 'ON9e1QkM1BPSMbeDWGHFgxksnolmRP7Q', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'HIT', 'Age': '50', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'cf-request-id': '047eabece000009e37d08e1200000001', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '5c1148f49ac79e37-ATH'}
```

Headers on S3

```
{'x-amz-id-2': 'apFCJaAW2DSB75jrhb88BhuSHGNV6oWW9/RhPhMxSsvdELqEuzeBED6wDrcpZ8o9rzS+v9kVrp0=', 'x-amz-request-id': 'CC00D77EB673C6B7', 'Date': 'Tue, 11 Aug 2020 10:30:50 GMT', 'Last-Modified': 'Tue, 11 Aug 2020 10:18:59 GMT', 'ETag': '"3e8fd2271360bb9b73f2c5dad4cab18a"', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Type': 'image/png', 'Content-Length': '132662', 'Server': 'AmazonS3'}
```

Both have the same content type.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the image inside the Web page, you can add a metadata key `Content-Disposition` with the value of `inline`. [[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)]

Comment: How did you open it? @tsorn

Comment: By clicking the link on AWS, or by pasting it, makes no difference